# Teamcity compilation error only on triggered build

Tags: qt, teamcity

I have a few Qt projects being built by Teamcity. When I commit a change to **vcs to trigger a build**, I always got the same build error at the same step:

```
[15:27:20][CustomBuild] Rcc'ing resources.qrc...
[15:27:20][CustomBuild] The system cannot find the path specified.
[15:27:20][CustomBuild] Uic'ing src\commandcard.ui...
[15:27:20][CustomBuild] The system cannot find the path specified.
[15:27:20][CustomBuild] Uic'ing src\myclass.ui...
[15:27:20][CustomBuild] The system cannot find the path specified.
[15:27:20][CustomBuild] Uic'ing src\settings.ui...
...
```

But when I re-run the build with the same revisions **via the UI**, the build executes without errors. Even if I set a "Retry Build Trigger" to retry after first error, the error exists.

After a error, the supposed missing files exists correctly in the disk, as they are in version control.

Windows 7 64
TeamCity Professional 10.0.4 (build 42538) (but issue appeared in older versions too)

Question also posted to [Teamcity community forum](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000078050-Compilation-error-only-on-triggered-build).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my own answer here:

With help from Teamcity staff, I was able to find the source of error:

It was an error on a environment parameter that I created to be used in the build (QTDIR). It is a 'select' type parameter, which had the label value as default instead of the actual value.

Changing the default to correct value fixed the issue.